# How do I change the default tableViewCell margins on iOS 7.1?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7.1, uitableview, ios8.3

My problem is that I cannot satisfy all three of these requirements with the same setup:

1. I primarily need the cells to line up with the separator insets on
   both 7.1 & 8.3.
2. In cells with no disclosure indicators, I need the
   right edge of the content (i.e. the rightLabel) to line up with the
   right edge of the content of cells that do have a disclosure
   indicator (i.e. the right edge of the disclosure indicator).
3. In cells with a disclosure indicator, I need the distance between the
   rightLabel and the disclosure indicator equal to the distance
   between the disclosure indicator and the right edge of the screen.

I can ameliorate the first and second problems by setting all constraints to the superview without margins (as is the case in all cells titled, “No Margin”), but when I do this there is too much white space between the edge of the rightLabel and the disclosure indicator (as shown in the fourth cell). 
I can resolve the second and third problems by setting all constraints relative to margins, but when I do this iOS 7.1 sets tableViewCells to have a default margin of 8pts, which doesn’t match iOS 8.3.

I would like to avoid setting the right constraint to be an IBOutlet and modifying it on the fly. The images I have posted are a quick mock-up that I’ve made to demonstrate the problem, but the app that I’m working on has many different tableViewCell subclasses and it would be very costly to have to manage all of these manually.

---

**Previous Attempts**

I have tried implementing the following code onto the tableViewController’s tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method,

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}
```

and I didn’t see any difference in behavior.

I have also tried implementing the following code onto the tableCell’s layoutSubviews method

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [self setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0);];
}
```

and this didn’t affect much of anything, except is caused the NoMargin cells on to be closer to the left edge than the separator inset on the iPhone 6+.

---

I feel like the most likely solution lies in changing the default tableViewCell margins in iOS 7.1 (hence the title), but I may be wrong and am very open to ideas.